# mongodb is not accessible through IP address 35.x.x.x

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I have installed mongo DB on window server that is accessible on `localhost:27017`  but not accessible on `35.x.x.x:27017`.

I checked:

27017 Port is open.
mongoDB is running.

output of: `netstat -anb | findstr :27017`

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:51186        127.0.0.1:27017        TIME_WAIT
```

my **mongos.conf** file is

```
dbpath = d:\MongoDB\Database
logpath = d:\MongoDB\Logs\log.txt
noauth = true # use 'true' for options that don't take an argument
bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Clearly it's not listening on the 35.* address.

Comment: Hi Shubham Batra, and welcome to dba.stackexchange. Can I make an observation: your mongos.conf file seems to be using the very old pre-YAML format, but since version 2.6 the YAML format has been standard. Do you have the option change your config file to use the YAML format, with the [bindIp flag](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, you have a typo at your config.  There should be `bindIp` and not `bind_ip`.

Comment: The conf file seems to be using the [pre-YAML legacy format](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip), which specifies bind_ip. However, that guidance is so old that I wouldn't be confident in it working that way in the current MongoDB version.

Comment: @VinceBowdren you are absolutely right, I had already forgotten 2.6 config file format.. :-)